# Gradle writing a task for replacing string in a file with environment variable, before build

Tags: android, replace, android-gradle-plugin, environment-variables, build.gradle

My Android app contains a .json file which contains the code,

```
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "GOOGLE_SERVICES"
        }
      ]
```

GOOGLE_SERVICES is in my system as an environment variable. I want to replace GOOGLE_SERVICES with the API key in my system variable before gradle executes build. Is there any way to write a task which executes before build, which does all that?